# How to use a variable without shape in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I try to use a variable without shape in tensorflow. My code is

```
sen_var_1 = tf.Variable(np.float32, trainable=False, validate_shape=False, expected_shape=[None, None, 300])
sen_1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None, 300], dtype=np.float32, name="q1")
sen_assign_1 = tf.assign(sen_var_1, sen_1, validate_shape=False)
```

I will run session with `sen_assign_1` when train begin, and each epoch I want to use `sen_var_1`. But it seems that `expected_shape` is not work in sen_var_1. So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure you feed something in for the placeholder "sen_1"? Here's a self contained example that runs

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sen_var_1 = tf.Variable(np.float32, trainable=False, validate_shape=False, expected_shape=[None, None, 300])
sen_1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None, 300], dtype=np.float32, name="q1")
sen_assign_1 = tf.assign(sen_var_1, sen_1, validate_shape=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(sen_1,feed_dict={sen_1:np.zeros((2,2,300))}))
```

Comment: This question is happened when tensorflow construct graph, not sess.run().